# how to fix Import Error: No module named... in python with VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to import a module into vsCode. I have attached some photos of my current set up right. Things to note:

- I am running the project in a virtual environment
- My interpreter is set up to use this virtual env
- I have my python:path set to run through the environment
- I have the required modules in env/lib/ folder.

[image]
[image]

This results in an **import error** even though I believe I have taken the correct steps in setting up my python project in vscode. If someone has experienced anything similar can you please provide input on how to solve this issue?

Comment: VSCode is an ide

Comment: i realize that, i am trying to use it as a python development environment right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install code-runner and place code below in settings.json folder

```
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "python3 -u",
    }
```

"python": "(the python version with modules) -u",

Comment: That did the trick for me. I had the extension "Code Runner" (version 0.11.1) installed already. The "python" setting in "executorMap" seems to have the default value `python -u`. Changing it to `python3 -u` fixed the problem with the import error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you never installed the requests module.

You need to do

`pip install requests`

for Python to find it.

Comment: i have done that and can see the module in my library folder